# Icons not showing when using the jquery-ui-rails gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

Im using the jquery-ui-rails (https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) gem in my rails 3.2.13 project. In my application.js i have

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

And in **vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui.js**

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

**application.css**

```
*= require jquery-ui
```

And in **vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css**

```
 *= require jquery.ui.all
```

But icons are not showing for example, ui-icon-search does not show the search icon. How can i fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any CSS code for the icons?

Comment: In the browser i see a jqueury.ui.theme.css which contains the css for icons

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how you're trying to use the icons? Are they meant to appear in some of the JQuery UI elements?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a paths issue with the jquery-ui images path

- the css file looks for images at url(images/...)
- when assets are precompiled, application.css gets moved to the top level
- but images are in the /images dir

I solved by:

- moving the jquery-ui css file to the top level
- updating its calls to images by prepending the theme dir name
- ie, url(my-theme-name/images/....)

Now it works both in dev and production.